# Modal dialog's onshow not called after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-modal, postback

I have a Bootstrap modal dialog that I am using to populate with data when user clicks on "Edit" in a jQuery data table. There is a Cancel and Submit button on this modal.

When I open the modal and click Cancel and then select another table row and click "Edit", everything is fine; data gets populated correctly each time "Edit" is clicked. However, if I do a postback by clicking "Submit" on the modal and then click "Edit" again, modal opens and no data is there.

I am using modal's on('show.bs.modal', ...) to populate it and it never gets hit after a postback is done.

```
// This is called when "Edit" in data table row is clicked
function showEdit(var1, var2) {debugger
    $('#hfVar1').val(var1);
    $('#hfVar2').val(var2);
    showEditModal();
}

function showEditModal() {debugger
    $("#spnEditHeader").text("Edit Something");
    $('#editModal').modal('show');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // This populates the jQuery data table
    showTable(somthing, anotherThing);

    // This is executed as long there is no postback; 
    // once a postback is perfoemd this is not hit, modal not populated
    $('#editModal').modal({
        keyboard: true,
        backdrop: "static",
        show: false
    }).on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {debugger
        var var1= $('#hfVar1').val();
        var var2= $('#hfVar2').val();

        //make ajax call to populate items
        populateMPOOEdit(var1, var2);
    });
    ....
});

//This is the button in modal that causes postback
<div class="modal-footer">
    <div id="divEditButtons" style="text-align: center;">
        <button id="btnCancel" class="btn btn-info2" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Cancel">Cancel</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Update">Update</button>
    </div>
</div>

// "Submit" button's click handler
$(document).on("click", "#btnSubmit", function (event) {
    // Validate data (client side validation)
    var isValid = validateUpdate();

    // Also need a server side validation checking for duplicate name, using ajax to do this
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '<%= ResolveUrl("services/mpoo.asmx/NameExists") %>',
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({ "Name": name }),
    }).done(function (data) {
        var result = data.d;

        if (result != '') {
            nameExists = JSON.parse(data.d);

            if (nameExists == "true") {
                $("#lblErrName").text("Duplicate Name");
                $("#lblEditErrName").show();
                isValid = false;
            }
            if (isValid) {
                __doPostBack('btnSubmit', JSON.stringify({
                    action: "SaveUpdate", Var1: var1, ..., Varn: varn
                }));
                $('#editModal').modal('hide');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;  // to prevent modal from closing if there are errors on page
});
```

Comment: did you check for errors? and are you saying this fn populateMPOOEdit does NOT get called?

Comment: I did not see any errors; and yes, as soon as there is a postback, the part with .on('show.bs.modal', function(e){ ...}) that includes the populate function does not get hit. I can see it hitting showEdit() and then showEditModal() but that's it.

Comment: is this the code that causes your postback? 

 __doPostBack('btnSubmit', JSON.stringify({
                    action: "SaveUpdate", Var1: var1, ..., Varn: varn
                }));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function like this:

```
//basically everything you had in your document.ready function
function myJsFunc() {
  // This populates the jQuery data table
  showTable(somthing, anotherThing);

  // This is executed as long there is no postback; 
  // once a postback is perfoemd this is not hit, modal not populated
  $('#editModal').modal({
    keyboard: true,
    backdrop: "static",
    show: false
  }).on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {debugger
    var var1= $('#hfVar1').val();
    var var2= $('#hfVar2').val();

    //make ajax call to populate items
    populateMPOOEdit(var1, var2);
  });
....
}
```

Then in your Page_Load event handler in your codebehind, try putting this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "some random name for your script", "myJsFunc();", true);
```

Comment: When I replace $(document).ready(function () with function myJsFunc() and add the code behind line, I get function myJsFunc in not defined. I added RegisterClientScript in page load().

Comment: can you make sure you have myJsFunc declared in your <head />...and then change Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScript to Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript - i made a mistake there.

Comment: same thing. I copied everything that was in $(document).ready() to a js function, moved the function to head section, removed $(document).ready(), added registerstartup script, still have the same problem.

Comment: I marked your response as the answer; however, I had to make a few changes: I created the js function but only moved the editModal part of $(document).ready() to it, left everything else intact; moved this function to head section of aspx file, added page.clientscript... to page_load() of .cs file in the "else" section of "if (!Page.IsPostBack)". Then it worked.

Comment: yeah, basically you just need to have your myJsFunc declared BEFORE it gets called. i usually call my javascript initialization methods at the end of the page near the last <html> tag, instead of using $(document).ready(). i THINK that mightve also worked...but i havent used webforms in a while so im kind of shabby.